# Any ways to use "space:delete" by part of partial key in Tarantool?

Tags: tarantool

The documentation says "delete cannot work with partial keys". What is your recommendation how to solve it. For example create new index, use cycle delete or any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete values in a loop using a primary key.

```lua
#!/usr/bin/env tarantool

local json = require('json')

local function key_from_tuple(tuple, key_parts)
    local key = {}
    for _, part in ipairs(key_parts) do
        table.insert(key, tuple[part.fieldno] or box.NULL)
    end
    return key
end

box.cfg{}

box.once('init', function()
    box.schema.space.create('s')
    box.space.s:create_index('pk')
    box.space.s:create_index('sk', {
        unique = false,
        parts = {
            {2, 'number'},
            {3, 'number'},
        }
    })
end)

box.space.s:truncate()
box.space.s:insert{1, 1, 1}
box.space.s:insert{2, 1, 1}

print('before delete')
print('---')
box.space.s:pairs():each(function(tuple)
    print(json.encode(tuple))
end)
print('...')

local key_parts = box.space.s.index.pk.parts
for _, tuple in box.space.s.index.sk:pairs({1}) do
    local key = key_from_tuple(tuple, key_parts)
    box.space.s.index.pk:delete(key)
end

print('after delete')
print('---')
box.space.s:pairs():each(function(tuple)
    print(json.encode(tuple))
end)
print('...')

os.exit()
```

In the example above a common case is handled using `key_from_tuple` function. Things may be simpler when you know which fields form a primary key. Say, if it is the first field:

```lua
for _, tuple in box.space.s.index.sk:pairs({1}) do
    box.space.s.index.pk:delete(tuple[1])
end
```

The new key_def module that was added in tarantool-2.2.0-255-g22db9c264 (not released yet, but availiable from our 2.2 repository) simplifies extracting a key from a tuple, especially in case of json path indexes:

```lua
#!/usr/bin/env tarantool

local json = require('json')
local key_def_lib = require('key_def')

box.cfg{}

box.once('init', function()
    box.schema.space.create('s')
    box.space.s:create_index('pk')
    box.space.s:create_index('sk', {
        unique = false,
        parts = {
            {2, 'number', path = 'a'},
            {2, 'number', path = 'b'},
        }
    })
end)

box.space.s:truncate()
box.space.s:insert{1, {a = 1, b = 1}}
box.space.s:insert{2, {a = 1, b = 2}}

print('before delete')
print('---')
box.space.s:pairs():each(function(tuple)
    print(json.encode(tuple))
end)
print('...')

local key_def = key_def_lib.new(box.space.s.index.pk.parts)
for _, tuple in box.space.s.index.sk:pairs({1}) do
    local key = key_def:extract_key(tuple)
    box.space.s.index.pk:delete(key)
end

print('after delete')
print('---')
box.space.s:pairs():each(function(tuple)
    print(json.encode(tuple))
end)
print('...')

os.exit()
```

([source of the code](https://github.com/tarantool/doc/issues/768))

Comment: Thanks! What is the difference between pairs() and select()?

Comment: select() fetches all matching tuples into the Lua memory at once that can cause a Lua error if the Lua memory limit will be reached (2 GiB AFAIR). pairs() creates an iterator that can be traversed with `for` tuple-by-tuple. General recommendation here is to use select() only when you are sure that the result set will be small.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Tarantool 2.1, you can use SQL syntax for that ('delete from ... where ...').

However, be aware that Tarantool will try to perfrom this in a transaction, so if you're trying to delete too many tuples, it will lock transaction thread for some time.